# Iframe not updating

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, webmatrix, auto-update

I have WebMatrix 3 installed and have a theme i uploaded activated.  This theme is displayed via an iframe in a MVC3 razor application. This application changes the themes' CSS but when a change is done the theme does not update to the changes. Also I noticed that it takes 24 hours to update.

Example:
I change programatically font-family from Calibri to Tahoma. But the theme saves the changes and when it is run it shows Calibri font (when it is set Tahoma).

Why? is there a setting?  Please Help

Comment: Have you pressed ctrl+F5?

Comment: Hi kyle thx for your solution.. Yes I tried but nothing happens.. Also I refresh it programatically

Comment: Weirdly it works for me in my Resolutions app. It also uses an iFrame to preview sites at certain breakpoints, when the CSS doesn't load in, I ctrl+F5 it and everything is fine. You say there's a 24 hour wait between updates? Could it be some server issue?

Comment: I know it's weird the thing is that not only the iframe does not update even when i run the theme from webmatrix it does not work :(

Answer (score 1):

I think, the problem is with HTTP headers which return the HTML page which you embeded as iframe. Also can be a problem with HTTP headers of CSS files.
Here is code for PHP:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");  
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```